# Can you still XSS against this filter?

Tags: regex, xss

I have a profile field that users can post their data onto. I block anything with the following regex pattern `/<(.+?)>/`

It blocks anything that starts with < and ends with >. Will this prevent XSS? I mean, there isn't much they can do now without being able to use the  <> HTML tags.

Comment: Don't do that.  You should properly escape data when rendering HTML.

Comment: The answer is yes, actually. Anyway, this approach is doomed to failure. Use a template that does proper entity encoding.

Comment: @Antimony How is it still possible? They really don't have any way of inputting it?

Answer (score 4):

There are in fact xss attacks that don't require a closing bracket.

For example, [this page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) lists one that works in IE

```
<IMG SRC="javascript:alert('XSS')"
```

Anyway the fact that you didn't realize this should teach you a lesson. Blacklisting like this is error prone and doomed to failure. You should use a template that applies the appropriate escaping (HTML entity encoding in this case but it depends on the context the output will appear in).

If you can get away with it, limit the input to a safe character set like alphanumerics so you don't have to worry about this in the first place. And make sure you handle unicode and null characters properly.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are vey forgiving when parsing html. I suspect the following input without closing the tag, would work:

```
<input onfocus=alert(1) autofocus type=text
```

Use entity escaping or a whitelist instead

Oh, and . does not match \n, so there you have another bypass:

```
<script
>
```